# Problems with accelerometer's reading taking interval

Tags: android, accelerometer

How can i set the reading taking interval for accelerometer? I have tried to insert a value in the registerlistener but it still running at the same interval. I inserted 5000 * 1000 but it still running at the same interval. What can i do to set an interval for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly set the interval for accelerometer reading, as the system controls this. The only thing you can do is to use these flags when registering your listener:

```
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST).

If you want to update the values on the screen at some frequency though, you can do it with runnable for example. You could also measure time in onSensorChanged() and update your variables only if specific amount of time has passed.

Comment: I got an error putting registerlistener in runnable, how can i fix it?

Comment: You should register listener in onCreate()